# Objective-C object creation methods differences

Tags: objective-c, initialization

What would be the main differences between these two methods:

```
+ (id)videoGameWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle publisher:(NSString *)newPublisher year:(int)newYear {
    VideoGame *game = [[[VideoGame alloc] init] autorelease];
    game.title = newTitle;
    game.publisher = newPublisher;
    game.year = newYear;

    return game;
}

- (id)initVideoGameWithTitle:(NSString *)newTitle publisher:(NSString *)newPublisher year:(int)newYear {

    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        self.title = newTitle;
        self.publisher = newPublisher;
        self.year = newYear;
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: The first method is not an initialiser: it’s a [convenience constructor](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocAllocInit.html). The second method is an attempt to be an initialiser, but fails at that since it’s a class method that tries to behave as an instance method. As a side note, the second method doesn’t follow Cocoa’s convention of naming initialisers as `init…`

Comment: @Bavarious - +1 for your comment. I've fixed the typo in the question since I suspect @Peter intended the second method to actually be a properly-named initializer. (The method body certainly looks like that's what he had in mind.)

Comment: @sherm Pendley - Rolling back your edits. You've changed the question completely - You're assuming that the OP really did make that many typos - making it a different question.

Comment: @Bavarious why is the second method a class method that tries to behave as an instance method? The second method is declared with "-" thus making it an instance method I believe. @Sherm Pendley - I believe you're correct with your assumptions, though now that the questions has been edited I don't remember what exactly I wrote initially. Can I see how my original question looked?

Comment: Yes, where it says "edited," click on the "xx mins ago" to see a list of all the revisions. Originally, it was declared identically to the first method. Looked like a copy-n-paste typo to me, especially given how the body of the method was written.

Comment: @Sherm - Ah thanks, yes you're correct with your edits then. @Bavarious - you can disregard my question then. Since your answer was meant for my original unedited question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is a class method that creates an object that the caller does not own and must not release. The second (aside from the typo in your original question) is an initializer, and since the caller has to call it in combination with `+alloc`, it returns an object that the caller owns and must release.

For a full explanation, including a description of which method names imply ownership and which do not, have a look at Apple's [Memory Management Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/MemoryMgmt.html).